# Converting form text in HTML into an array in JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I am attempting to create an online solver for the maximum subarray problem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

I planned on taking user-input numbers from a textbox and converting them into an int array in JS, however my JS does not seem to be running at all.
Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> findMaxSum </title>
        <script src="findMaxSum.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> findMaxSum </h1>
        <form id="formarray" action="">
            <p> Enter numbers with spaces, i.e. "1 2 3 4 5": </p>
            <input type="text" id="array"> <br>
            <button id="sum">findMaxSum!</button>
            <br>
        </form>
        <p id="answer">The answer is: </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my JS. note: the map(function(item)) part of the code is intended to break apart the string from the form into an int array.

```
"use strict";

function findMaxSum() {
    var array = document.getElementById("array").split(" ").map(function(item) {
        return parseInt(item, 10);
    });
    var sumButton = document.getElementById("sum");
    sumButton.onclick = findMaxSum;
    var loopSum = 0;
    var currentMax = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        loopSum += array[i];
        if (currentMax < loopSum) {
            currentMax = loopSum;
        } else if (loopSum < 0) {
            loopSum = 0;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The answer is: " + currentMax;
}

window.onload = findMaxSum;
```

Currently, when I type in numbers into the textbox and submit, the numbers disappear and nothing happens. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array` variable is `object`. You have to split the value of `<input type="text" id="array">` not the object element.

```
var array = document.getElementById("array");
    array = array.value.split(" ").map(function (item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});
```

Or simpler:

```
var array = document.getElementById("array").value.split(" ").map(function (item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});
```

Comment: you could just do this : `array.value.split(" ").map(parseFloat);`

Comment: @Khalid I've added the simpler way to.

Comment: Or `...map(Number);` ;-)

Comment: one word off...much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are using button inside form, which is by default of type `submit` type, that is the reason why the page goes blank, it gets submitted. So either you don't use form tag or make the button as button type.

```
<button id="sum" type='button'>findMaxSum!</button> <!-- type attribute added -->
```

Below is the sample updated code, hope it helps you.

```js
"use strict";

function findMaxSum() {
  var array = document.getElementById("array").value.split(/\s/);
  var max = Math.max.apply(Math, array);
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The answer is: " + max;
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("sum").onclick = findMaxSum;
};
```

```html
<h1> findMaxSum </h1>
<form id="formarray" action="">
  <p>Enter numbers with spaces, i.e. "1 2 3 4 5":</p>
  <input type="text" id="array">
  <br>
  <button id="sum" type='button'>findMaxSum!</button>
  <br>
</form>
<p id="answer">The answer is:</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code -

```
  function findMaxSum() {
        var array = document.getElementById("array").value.split(" ").map(function(item) {
            return parseInt(item, 10);
        });
        var sumButton = document.getElementById("sum");
        sumButton.onclick = findMaxSum;
        var loopSum = 0;
        var currentMax = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            loopSum += array[i];
            if (currentMax < loopSum) {
                currentMax = loopSum;
            } else if (loopSum < 0) {
                loopSum = 0;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The answer is: " + currentMax;
    }

    window.onload = findMaxSum;
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the solution of the problem, you need to make following changes.

1. Update the event binding place

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
       var sumButton = document.getElementById("sum");
       sumButton.onclick = findMaxSum;
   };

   function findMaxSum() {
       // remove the update binding code from here
       // logic should come here
   }
   ```
2. Resolve a JS error

   ```
   document.getElementById("array").value.split(" ")
   ```
3. Update the html to avoid page refresh (add type)

   ```
   <button id="sum" type='button'>findMaxSum!</button>
   ```
4. Update the logic to address the problem

   ```
   var currentMax = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       var counter = i+1;
       while (counter < array.length) {
         var loopSum = array[i];
         for (var j = (i+1); j <= counter; j++) {
           loopSum += array[j];
           if(loopSum > currentMax) {
              currentMax = loopSum;
           }
         }
         counter++;
       }
   }
   ```

Here is a plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/AoPANUgKY5gbYYWUT1KJ?p=preview